# git pre-commit hook not running when running git commit -a

Tags: git, githooks

I have a local pre-commit hook which executes, and stops the commit as expected when I run 
`git commit`

Also, as expected, I can bypass the hook when I run `git commit -n ...`

However, running `git commit -am "My message"` or indeed, just `git commit -a` seems to bypass the hook and allow the commit to be processed.

Any idea why this may be happening?

**Edit**: Hook below.

```
PROJECT_ROOT=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
CHANGED=`git diff --stat -- $PROJECT_ROOT/myProj/myfile.ext | wc -l`
if [ $CHANGED -gt 0 ];
then
    echo "myfile.ext file has changed, are you sure you want to commit"
    echo "Use the -n parameter to process this commit."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Paste the hook too.

Comment: And just as you wrote that, I realised that my hook condition probably evaluates differently for each command.. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, it was user error..

The hook was running in both instances, however the logic I used to detect a change in my file didn't work when the -a command was supplied.

Checking against the remote repo did the trick.

`` CHANGED=`git diff origin/master --stat -- $PROJECT_ROOT/myProj/myfile.ext | wc -l` ``

**edit**: thanks to @torek, a more appropriate way to check for a change is:

```
CHANGED=`git diff --cached --stat -- $PROJECT_ROOT/myProj/myfile.ext | wc -l`
```

Comment: That's not "checking against the remote repo", that's comparing the source tree associated with a *local* commit labeled `origin/master` with the source tree in your *work-tree*. It will give you different results but probably not what you are looking for: the contents of the work-tree are not necessarily the contents to be committed; what is to be committed is whatever is in the index. In general, one should compare the `HEAD` commit to the index, which for humans is done with `git diff --cached` (script-writers prefer the "plumbing commands" so as to not be affected by user configs).

Comment: Ah yes - I may be guilty of copying that original comparison line from another SO question :) Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: That's definitely an improvement. :-) I think it's important to note, though, that you literally cannot *ever* look at anything in the *remote* repo, you can only look at your own repo. You can (at any time) `git fetch` from a remote to get as up-to-date *about* that other repo as possible, but this simply copies their stuff into *your* repo. Everything else you do is inherently local, and the remote may be changing while you work. That's a fundamental property of distributed repositories, so it's not like there's anything to *do* about it, but it's worth remembering.

Comment: Another note, you can save the process and pipe needed for `--stat ... | wc -l` by using `git diff --quiet ...` (implies `--exit-code`) and inspecting the result.  A nonzero result indicates that the file has changes.